# change cryptomatte setitings with python

Tags: python, rendering

I am trying to turn passes on and off via python. But I can't find out how to change the cryptomatte settings:

this is what the info panel shows when I click on Cryptomatte - Object:

```py
bpy.context.scene.use_pass_crypto_object = True
```

it returns this:

```py
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'use_pass_crypto_object'
```

so I tried each of these lines, but none of them work:

```py
bpy.context.scene.view_layers["View Layer"].use_pass_crypto_object = False

bpy.context.scene.render.use_pass_crypto_object = False

bpy.context.scene.use_pass_crypto_object = False
```

This one doesnt throw an error, but also does nothing, and it is not a UI refresh issue:

```py
bpy.context.scene.cycles.pass_crypto_accurate = False
```

Does somebody know how to access it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**View the UI source**

In *`User Preferences > Interface > Display`* turn on developer extras. Sounds like you already have.  When the path in button hover is dodgy, if available click view source on a field of interest.

In this case it opens *`addons/cycles/ui.py`* in text editor at or around the CryptoMatte draw panel where this leaps out

```
cycles_view_layer = context.view_layer.cycles
```

Off to the python console:

```
>>> cycles_view_layer
bpy.data.scenes['Scene']...CyclesRenderLayerSettings

>>> cycles_view_layer.use_pass_crypto_
                                      asset
                                      material
                                      object
>>> cycles_view_layer.use_pass_crypto_object
True

>>> cycles_view_layer.pass_crypto_
                                  accurate
                                  depth
>>> cycles_view_layer.pass_crypto_depth
6

>>> cycles_view_layer.pass_crypto_depth = 10
>>>
```

can put in accurate mode with

```
cycles_view_layer.pass_crypto_accurate = True
```

Some more fiddling, the property is displayed as belonging to scene

```
>>> cycles_view_layer.id_data
bpy.data.scenes['Scene']

>>> C.scene.view_layers['RenderLayer'].cycles
bpy.data.scenes['Scene']...CyclesRenderLayerSettings

>>> cycles_view_layer
bpy.data.scenes['Scene']...CyclesRenderLayerSettings

>>> C.scene.view_layers['RenderLayer'].cycles is cycles_view_layer
False

>>> C.scene.view_layers['RenderLayer'].cycles == cycles_view_layer
True
```

Comment: Thanks batFINGER, this works! I will add this solution to my post

Answer (score -1):

solution from batFinger:

```py
from bpy import context
cycles_view_layer = context.view_layer.cycles
cycles_view_layer.use_pass_crypto_object=False
```

thanks!